# How can a client-side alert be shown after sending file with readfile()?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, alert, readfile

Say I have the following pages:

#### index.php

```
<html>
   <form action="/make_file" method="get">
    <select name="client" style="width: 80%;">
     <?php foreach($clients as $client): ?> 
       <option value="<?=$client;?>"><?=$client;?></option>
     <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" value="Download Client Info">
   </form>
</html>
```

#### make_file.php

```
<?php
     $client = $_GET['client'];
     //check that client is valid and grab client information from the database

     $tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), $clientName);
     $handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w");

     //create a txt file containing information about the client

     header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
     header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
     header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($tmpfname).'.txt"');
     header('Expires: 0');
     header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
     header('Pragma: public');
     header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($tmpfname));
     readfile($tmpfname);
     unlink($tmpfname);

     !!! //now here is where I'd like to create a custom message

?>
```

So in simple terms, I would like a user to be able to choose a client on *index.php*, then the *make_file.php* page will create and serve a text file with information about the client. But ideally, after that I would like to send a crafted alert message (via jquery/ajax..) to the user on *index.php*. The alert message will depend on the client and their information so it cannot be static.

I have tried several methods, but I'm having a problem with the fact that once you set the content-disposition header the whole output is put into the file (which is the expected behaviour) so I don't really know how to send this alert?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I execute some javascript after a file is downloaded?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14954121/how-do-i-execute-some-javascript-after-a-file-is-downloaded) or [Detect when browser receives file download](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download)

Comment: To the best of my knowledge, you cannot put the alert message code in the response from `make_file.php`. The only way I could see it working without a separate request would be setting the message as a cookie that the Javascript/jQuery would then parse as the message for the alert.

Answer (score 0):

Adapting the suggesion in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1106377/detect-when-browser-receives-file-download#answer-4168965), we can set a cookie using [setrawcookie()](http://php.net/setrawcookie) and [rawurlencode()](http://php.net/rawurlencode) <sup>1</sup> right before calling [readfile()](http://php.net/readfile).

```
$message = 'hey there you picked client: '.$client.' tmpfilename: '.$tmpfname;
setrawcookie('message', rawurlencode($message), 2147483647, "/");
```

Then in the client-side page (i.e. *index.php*) we can add JavaScript (could utilize jQuery functions if you really wanted to but the code below is *vanilla* JS). It uses [Event Delegation](http://jsforallof.us/2014/09/12/event-delegation/) to add an event listener (with [document.forms[0].addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener)) to the submission event on the form, [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) to create a function that runs periodically.

In that interval function, it checks for a cookie being set utilizing [document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie). If a message is found in the cookies, then it decodes the message with [decodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURIComponent), sends that message to the [alert()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/alert) and clears the interval using [clearInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval).

```
<!-- form HTML-->
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',function(DOMReadyEvent) {
  document.forms[0].addEventListener('submit',startMessageCheck);
});
var messageCheck;
function startMessageCheck(formSubmitEvent) {
  messageCheck = window.setInterval(function() {
    var message = getCookie('message');
    if (message) {
      var decodedMessage = decodeURIComponent(message);
      alert('message: '+decodedMessage);
      deleteCookie('message');
      window.clearInterval(messageCheck);
    }
  },1000);
}
function getCookie( name ) {
  var parts = document.cookie.split(name + "=");
  if (parts.length == 2) {
          return parts.pop().split(";").shift();
  }
}
function deleteCookie( cName ) {
  document.cookie = cName + "=; Path=/; Expires=" + new Date( 0 ).toUTCString();
}
</script>
```

A demonstration of this can be seen on [this page](http://elliott.andrewz.org/readfile/index.php).

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Initially I used [setcookie()](http://php.net/setcookie) but was having issues with the default string encoding in the client-side.</sub>